Swift - Snackbar with StackView, position bug when disappearing
I notice something wired when my snackbar will dismiss.
The label, decrease your height inside the stackview, pretty strange, when it will dismiss.
But this problem, only occur when snackbar style is rounded.
In this branch (my repo essentials), you can see on example, whats going on.
Below, is the calling for snackbar you can find on example and GIF animated:
let snackbar = LCSnackBarView(style: .rounded, orientation: .top)
snackbar
    .configure(text: "Hello my friend!")
    .configure(textFont: .systemFont(ofSize: 16.0, weight: .regular))
    .configure(textColor: .black)
    .configure(backgroundColor: UIColor(hex: "#CCCCCC"))
    .present()

Any hints, please let me know!
Thanks


Please post all the necessary code to debug here on SO, so people can help you.

The code is too large, and need some algorithm that i made, so that why i put the REPO LINK, please, download and test, simple : )
